# I get both ')' & '}' expected in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code :

```
    void Update () {

    Vector2 ChrP = transform.position;

    if (ChrP == new Vector2(-3.03f, 3.02f))
    {
        if (float RightPress = Input.GetAxisRaw("Right")){
            transform.position = new Vector2(-1.36f, 3.02f);

        } if (float DownPress = Input.GetAxisRaw("Down")) {
            transform.position = new Vector2(-3.03f, 1,401f);

        } else {
            return null;
        }


    }
```

So in this code i get the problem : ')' & '}' expected and have not been able to solve it for a long time
The problem occours on line 7 & 10 and 13.

Comment: Where is the bracket that closes your method?

Comment: This won't compile: `if (float RightPress = Input.GetAxisRaw("Right"))`. What condition are you trying to check there? Please explain the intent of that `if` statement, and also the `float DownPress` one following it.

Comment: im trying to check if the position is equal to -3.03f, 3.02f and if that is so check if press right or down change to the following positions

Comment: That doesn't answer the question very well. Is `DownPress` a variable that you declared somewhere else?

Comment: I added this on the top: public class CharacterAction : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 30;
    public FormStartPosition StartPosition { get; set; }
    public float RightPress { get; private set; }
    public float LeftPress { get; private set; }
    public float DownPress { get; private set; }

Comment: `GetAxisRaw("Right")` and `GetAxisRaw("Down")` sounds wrong on principle - your axes are usually called `"Horizontal"` and `"Vertical"`. Also a method with return type `void` cannot have a `return null;` in it

Comment: Already the code `void M() { if (float foo = 0f) { } }` gives several errors, including `)` expected and `}` expected. You cannot declare a new variable inside the "condition" (`boolean_expression`) belonging to an `if` statement like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason for this is that you're trying to create a variable/field in an if statement and then comparing that to ... nothing :

```
// here you're trying to create new variable of type float
// and assign its value instead of comparing if Axis <> 0
if (float RightPress = Input.GetAxisRaw("Right")){
    transform.position = new Vector2(-1.36f, 3.02f);
}
```

To fix that based on that you're not using `RightPress`, you can just check if an absolute value of `Input.GetAxisRaw(...)` is greater than `0` :

```
if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Right")) > 0.0f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(-1.36f, 3.02f);
}
```

---

Another issue is that your method returns `void` so basically you should return nothing and you're trying to return a `null` value :

```
else {
    return null;
}
```

Fix this by removing a `null` in here.

---

Last issue I'm seeing here is that your method lacks of closing bracket ( the `}` at the end of your method's body ). So the complete code should look like such :

```
void Update () 
{
    Vector2 ChrP = transform.position;
    if (ChrP == new Vector2(-3.03f, 3.02f))
    {
        if ( Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Right")) > 0.0f ) 
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(-1.36f, 3.02f);
        } 

        if ( Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Down")) > 0.0f ) 
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(-3.03f, 1.401f);
        }
    }
}
```